# How can I omit some of my elements while serializing my object with SimpleXML?

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

It may be a basic question, but I could not manage to find a correct answer. Maybe it is an exceptional usage of SimpleXML.

In SimpleXML (java)  I want to read some attributes of an object from XML and then save the Object again to another XML without writing those attributes.

I want to read "Question" object from this XML definition:

```
<question>
<questionID>0</questionID>
<category>tarih</category>
<difficultyLevel>80</difficultyLevel>
<text>Tarihte gelmiş geçmiş en büyük sınırlara ulaşan imparatorluk, aşağıdakilerden hangisidir?</text>
<alternatives length="4">
    <string>Britanya</string>
    <string>Roma</string>
    <string>Moğol</string>
    <string>Osmanlı</string>
</alternatives>
<answerID>0</answerID>
```

And Serialize it back as follows by eliminating the "alternatives" fields:

```
<question>
    <questionID>0</questionID>
    <category>tarih</category>
    <difficultyLevel>80</difficultyLevel>
    <text>Tarihte gelmiş geçmiş en büyük sınırlara ulaşan imparatorluk, aşağıdakilerden hangisidir?</text>
    <answerID>0</answerID>
</question>
```

Is this possible?

Edit: The java class definition of "Question":

```
public class Question {

    public final static int N_POSSIBLE_ANSWERS=4;

    public final static String[] ALTERNATIVE_CAPTIONS = {"A","B","C","D"};

    // Attributes

    @Element
    public int questionID;
    @Element
    public String category;
    @Element
    public int difficultyLevel;
    @Element
    public String text;
    @ElementArray
    private String[] alternatives;

    @Element(required=false)
    private int answerID = -1;
    // State variables

    private int nAddedAlternatives=0;

    public String[] getAlternatives() {
        return alternatives;           
    }

    public void addAlternative(String alternative){
        if(alternatives == null){
            alternatives = new String[N_POSSIBLE_ANSWERS];
        }
        alternatives[nAddedAlternatives] = alternative;
        nAddedAlternatives++;
    }

    public void clearAlternatives(){
        nAddedAlternatives = 0;
        alternatives = null;
    }


    public String getAlternative(int i){
        //String result = ALTERNATIVE_CAPTIONS[i];
        //result += ": ";
        String result = alternatives[i];
        return result;
    }

    public int getAnswer(){
        return answerID;
    }

    public void setAnswer(int answer){
    answerID = answer;
    }

}
```

The ElementArray defined as "alternatives" is the interest point of this question.

Best regards,
fercis

Comment: Show us the Java classes with the Simple annotations.

Comment: @ Tomalak: I actually use SimpleXML for object serialization, but when I define a variable as Element, it is included in output XML file while writing. When I do not, I cannot read those variables at all. I want to use some elements in reading, but not in writing. Reverse is possible by setting required = false flag.

@Tichodroma : Now I will edit my question and add the class definition.

Comment: Can you clearAlternatives() before you write? If alternatives is null the tag won't be included.

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem, but from the comments of people who work have experience at Simple Framework, I understand that there is probably no flag to use an attribute in reading but omit in writing.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below method to convert that

```
public static void convert(InputStream inputStream,OutputStream outputStream,List<String> result)  {
    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document document = builder.parse(inputStream);
        if(inputStream != null)
            inputStream.close();

        NodeList childNodes = document.getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes();

        Document writeDoc = builder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = writeDoc.createElement(document.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeName());

        for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node item = childNodes.item(i);
            if(result.contains(item.getNodeName())) {
                System.out.println("Skipped ...");
                continue;
            }
            Node node = item.cloneNode(true);
            writeDoc.adoptNode(node);
            rootElement.appendChild(node);
        }
        writeDoc.appendChild(rootElement);

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(writeDoc);
        transformer.transform(source, new StreamResult(outputStream));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the method which take the input as a InputStream, will return result in OutPutStream, will accept List of String that need to be filtered.